# How to force pdfminer to analyze layout from left to right ant top to bottom?

Tags: layout, pdfminer, pdftotext

I use a common code fro converting a pdf to text using pdfminer, something like this:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos,
                                      maxpages=maxpages, password=password,
                                      caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
            interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()
```

It's a good library and works well on many files, but sometimes it shows stupid layout analysis. For example in a two-columns pdf like the following, it first shows the text of the second column.

[image]

I guess in all or most English articles, the text runs from top to down and left to right. So, why pdfminer doesnt' follow this simple rule? Anyways, how can I force it to obey this processing?